# How can I change user group without delete record

Tags: django

On my website any user have only one group. And any user can change his group.
So it's made by

```
user.groups.clear()
```

and

```
user.groups.add(new_group)
```

But it's not efficient, because there is a two SQL query: DELETE, INSERT.
How can I change group by just UPDATE query?

Comment: mgibsonbr answer is good but I was wondering if you have many users changing their group each second? If it's not the case (meaning that changing group is not done really often) you should not care about this kind of inefficiency. Don't do premature optimisations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`User` and `Group` are related to each other using a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships). That means an intersection table exists relating both entities, and if you don't specify a model to map to it (using the `through` attribute) Django creates one for you. Looking at the sources for `django.contrib.auth.models` I see that's the case.

Fortunatly, you can access that intermediary model using the `through` attribute of the manager (in this case, `User.groups.through`). Then you can use it just like any regular model. Example:

```
>>> alice = User.objects.create_user('alice', 'alice@example.com', 'alicepw')
>>> employee = Group.objects.create(name='employee')
>>> manager = Group.objects.create(name='manager')

>>> alice.groups.add(employee)
>>> alice.groups.all()
[<Group: employee>]

>>> alice_group = User.groups.through.objects.get(user=alice)
>>> alice_group
<User_groups: User_groups object>
>>> alice_group.group = manager
>>> alice_group.save()

>>> alice.groups.all()
[<Group: manager>]
>>>
```

(newlines added for readability)

Comment: Thanks, man! Actually, I don't understand how, but it's works!